# Middle column is overflowing

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I got stuck on this one tiny tedious problem where I have 3 columns side by side and the middle column is spilling the text over to underneath the first column AND is half the width of the other columns. I tried setting the left and right column to %33.3 width and letting the middle column take care automatically, didn't help. I tried setting all columns to %33.3 that didn't fix it. I've removed all padding and margins and everything and it doesn't work. This happens on the 768px media query. I uploaded a zip with the queries and the rest of the pics and files. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3AQB2FIkek5b0FlazVuMjBPTzg/edit?usp=sharing
And here is visual of what I was talking about the spilling of text [image]

What am I doing wrong?

p.s.: ONLY seeking help for the 768 query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you float your three boxes/containers all of your content should remain in said containers. Have a look at my fiddle for a reference

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredczerew/L98hB/

```
/** CSS **/
body {    
background:#ccc;
width:100%;
}
section {
width:30%;
float:left;
}
#two {
padding:0 20px;
}



<body>
<section>nly five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</section>



<section id="two">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</section>


<section>and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five        centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</section>  

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch. My logic went wrong somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested on `column-count`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nbr7a/)

```
p {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap:   20px;  
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -moz-column-gap:      20px;
  column-count:         3;
  column-gap:           20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't floating the center column, hence why text is wrapping to the left when the left column floats.

**[This should work](http://jsfiddle.net/2Uwuq/)**

Looking at your code, there's a few things you could tweak to clean it up a little.

1. You mention ID's twice when targeting the columns. You don't need to do this, as an ID should be unique on the page it appears on, therefore you only need to target that element: instead of `#about #left`, you only need `#left`
2. You are using a different style set for each column, where one would do:

   ```
   .left-col, 
   .right-col, 
   .middle-col {
       width:33.2%
       float:left;
   }
   ```

3 Lastly, you appear to have generated each stylesheet by copying an existing one. That's a valid way to do it, but you end up making a huge amount of work for yourself by rre-specifying the same information many times. The cascading nature of the styles won't help you when you change one master style if you do it this way. Instead, you need to address each property in every single stylesheet.